# Using gradle test to execute Junit5 ExtendedCucumber test

Tags: gradle, cucumber-java, junit5

I want to be able to execute an ExtendedCucumber Class using `gradle test` rather than defining a separate cucumber task invoking the `cucumber.api.cli.Main` class.

I have the following ExtendedCucumber test runner:

```
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber 
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber::class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-
report.json",
    retryCount = 3,
    detailedReport = true,
    detailedAggregatedReport = true,
    overviewReport = true,
    //coverageReport = true,
    jsonUsageReport = "build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-report.json",
    usageReport = false,
    toPDF = true,
    excludeCoverageTags = ["@flaky"],
    includeCoverageTags = ["@passed"],
    outputFolder = "build/test-results/cucumber")
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = ["pretty:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-pretty.txt", "html:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-report.json", "usage:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-usage.json",
        "junit:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-results.xml"],
    glue = ["io.biomex.spog.steps"],
    features = ["classpath:features"])
class RunCukesJunitTest
```

Which executes from my IDE as expected, creating extended reports. And the following Junit5 configuration in gradle:

```
junitPlatform {
    platformVersion '1.0.2'
    reportsDir file('build/test-results/junit-platform') // this is the default
    filters {
        engines {
            include 'junit-jupiter'
            // exclude 'custom-engine'
        }
        tags {
            // include 'fast'
            //exclude 'slow'
        }
        selectors {
            file 'RunCukesJunitTest'
        }
        //includeClassNamePattern '^.*Test?'
        //excludeClassNamePattern '^.*Jpa?'
    }
    // enableStandardTestTask true
    // reportsDir file('build/test-results/junit-platform') // this is the default
    //logManager 'org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager'
}
```

Which works well finding and executing ordinary Junit tests. As you can see I've configured Junit5 to execute only the RunCukesJunitTest. The build runs normally, detecting the test, but doesn't run any tests any the output below:

```
Test run finished after 47 ms
[         1 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         1 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]



BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
```

I can run ordinary Cucumber test using a custom gradle task:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'html:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-html-report',
                '--plugin', 'json:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-report.json',
                '--plugin', 'pretty:build/test-results/cucumber/cucumber-pretty.txt', '--glue', 'io.biomex.spog.steps', 'src/test/resources/features/api']
        }
    }
}
```

And I think I can alter the above task to execute the ExtendedCucumber task. However, ideally I want all Junit tests, including the cucumber tests to be executed when I run the command `gradle test` or `gradle junitPlatformTest`.

Comment: about your last phrase... is it not enough to specify that `test.dependsOn cucumber` ? (and similiarly for  `junitPlatformTest `...)

Comment: I don't like the cucumber task shown above as it's just duplicating the annotation information in the RunCukesTest class. I found that it is cleaner to use JUnitCore to execute the RunCukesTest as it obviates the need to declare the java arguments, but this a legacy JUnit approach. I could add `test.dependsOn  cucumber` however, I get the following error: `
> Could not get unknown property 'testLogging' for task ':spog-api:cucumber' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.`   `test.dependsOn cucumber {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}`

Comment: I need those properties for JUnit5 tests to work: `test.dependsOn cucumber {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}`

Comment: After digging around most people suggest ignoring report generation in Gradle and handing it off to CI server i.e. Jenkins with the report generation plugins. I've settled for this: ```task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['io.biomex.spog.steps.RunCukesTest']
        }
    }
}```